# Why is django using sqlite3 when I want to use postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I get this stupid error when I try to log into admin.

```
Exception Type:
OperationalError 

Exception Value:
unable to open database file

Exception Location:
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in get_new_connection, line 346
```

The question is, why is this even referring to sqlite??

In my settings, I specified the DB engine as postgresql.

I tried to delete current db, make new one do a whole new syncdb but with no success.

---------edit with settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or           '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

(name, user, pw has been taken out)

Comment: Probably your settings file is wrong. Maybe you should post the value of the `DATABASE` dictionary from `settings.py`

Comment: Just posted it now :)

Comment: and user name, password

Comment: @kroolik : ... which is why I had already removed my comment :)

Comment: Are you using postgresql in your computer or into a remote server?

Comment: Create a database, then add the values for name, username and password to your database settings

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Apache/nginx or anything other than django's development server? One possible explanation is that your server is still referring to the old settings.py .

If that's the case, along with syncdb you will also need to manually restart the HTTP server.